# Associating a value with another value generated randomly

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here's what I'm looking to do:

I have a series of survey questions that are generated randomly for the user.

What I want is to associate two values with each other, the integer value of the question number that was generated randomly, and a integer value representative of how many times this user has answered this question. I want to be able to save and retrieve these associated values later so I can increment how many times the user has answered this question.

So, how do you associate two different integer values to each other, save, and update them later?

I'm starting with this code.

```
QuestionSelected = arc4random_uniform(4);
```

For example once this outcome was generated:

QuestionSelected = 1

I would need to establish a new value that I can associate with that question's value (1), increment it, and then save each time the user returns to this question.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can use `NSMutableDictionary` and save key value where `QuestionSelected` would be key and `NumberOfAttempts` would be value, each time you found same question update its `NumberOfAttempts`. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Association of one value with another is a "map". `NSDictionary` is the standard mapping collection in Cocoa, so you can use that:

```
NSNumber * timesSeen = myMutableDictionary[@(selectedQuestion)];
if( !timesSeen ){
    timesSeen = @(0);
}
myMutableDictionary[@(selectedQuestion)] = @([timesSeen intValue] + 1);
```

Since an array in essence associates its indexes, which are numbers, with values, another option is to use an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSNumber * timesSeen = myMutableArray[selectedQuestion];
myMutableArray[selectedQuestion] = @([timesSeen intValue] + 1);
```

An `NSArray` can't be sparse, so you would have to fill it up with zeroes when you create it:

```
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++ ){
    [myMutableArray addObject:@(0)];
}
```

As you may notice, dealing with numerical values that need to change in a Cocoa collection is a bit of a pain, because the `NSNumber`s have to be unboxed and replaced each time. So a third option would be a C array:

```
int * viewCounts;

viewCounts = calloc(numQuestions, sizeof(int));

viewCounts[selectedQuestion]++;
```

`calloc()` gets a chunk of memory for you and fills it with zeros. You will need to release that memory by calling `free(viewCounts)` when you are done with the array.

Comment: This is all great information and helps me exactly. Thank you!

Comment: ok so let me know if I'm on the right track here., the number of questions will always change because I'm allowing for my users to submit their own questions. I cannot set a defined amount of keys in my NSMutableDictionary. So what I would need to do is first check if there is currently a defined key for the selected question, and if not add it. Right?